# Perform a command on multiple files using command line

Tags: linux, command-line, mingw, wildcard

Say I have the following files:

```
myfile1_1.dat
myfile1_2.dat
myfile2_1.dat
myfile2_2.dat
...
```

and I want to use the same command on each of them (whilst ignoring other files in the directory that do not begin with `myfile`). Is there an easy way of doing this?

So far, I have been toying with wildcards:

```
mycommand myfile*.dat
```

**EDIT:**  I am using both Linux and MinGW

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`mycommand myfile*.dat` will only work if `mycommand` supports multiple files. If it doesn't, you can use `xargs` to pass a single file to `mycommand` as shown below:

```
echo myfile*.dat | xargs -n 1 mycommand
```

Alternatively, use a loop:

```
for file in myfile*.dat; do
    mycommand "$file"
done
```

Comment: I have to protest the `xargs` example on the grounds that readers may not understand that filenames will be split across whitespace. OP's example files may be immune, but future readers' may not. Use the loop, Luke.

Answer (score 1):

If you're doing this in Linux, I usually use `xargs -n1`

```
ls | xargs -n1 echo File:
```